# SSL certificate for a domain with services running on different ports

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a server that has different services running on different ports. For example: https://hostname:9000.com or wss://hostname:4536.com, etc. Now what will be the single right SSL certificate that could secure all those services?
I read about WildCard Cerificates that secure all the sub domains on a domain. Would trying a WildCard Certificate the right thing to do in this case here?

Comment: Port number comes after the hostname `https://example.com:9000` and `https://example.com:4536`, and is not part of the domain name and in particular is not a subdomain, and only the domain name is in the cert, so you (can) use a cert for `example.com` for all ports.

Comment: Thanks. Resolves my confusions :)