# How to fix Mixed Content errors on SSL folders in a multiple port on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, http, ssl, iis

In our current setup, we are using https for the main domain `http://example.com`. In one script we have called different URL with port `http://example.com:6037`.
How can we use SSL for `http://example.com:6037`?

We are getting the error mentioned below:

> This request has been blocked. the content must be shared over https

Comment: You should be able to use `https://example.com:6037` according to [SSL certificate for a domain with services running on different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916282/ssl-certificate-for-a-domain-with-services-running-on-different-ports#comment63288294_37916282).

Comment: But in IIS, example.com work fine but url with different port redirecting to https and shows error like 'This request has been blocked. the content must be shared over https'                                               Could you please share any help link to configure multiple ports with https in IIS

Comment: In IIS, when you added the binding for port 6037, did you select the correct certificate? Related: [Can I use another port other than 443 for SSL communication?](https://superuser.com/q/791218/272824)

Comment: Thanks for your support.  We have tried with the help of this link@https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/sep/23/hosting-signalr-under-sslhttps#using-a-full-iis-certificate.                                                     Hope it will work after service restart