# How to solve HTTPS security is compromised (Http & Https Mixed Content error) when files are in different folder?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, https

ASP.NET 4.0
In the website, only the login page use HTTPs

in the file https://domain/p/account/Login.aspx

it contains:

```
<script src="../Scripts/abc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Styles/def.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

in I.E., error:

- HTTPS security is compromised by http://domain/p/Scripts/abc.js HTTPS
  security is compromised by http://domain/p/Styles/def.css

in Chrome, error:

- Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain/p/account/Login.aspx' was
  loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
  'http://domain/p/Scripts/abc.js'. This request has been blocked; the
  content must be served over HTTPS.

  Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain/p/account/Login.aspx' was
  loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
  'http://domain/p/Styles/def.css'. This request has been blocked; the
  content must be served over HTTPS.

How to solve?

When I hard code the src path as https... it also treat it as http and display the same error

```
<script src="https://domain/p/Scripts/abc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm baffled as to why you're getting [mixed content](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/) when your HTML has a *relative path* to a (presumably!) HTTPS [base URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).  Q: What is your web server?  Do you have admin control?  ALSO: look [here](https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57608385/421195)

Comment: paulsm4: Do you mean the OS of the server? Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard

Comment: Q: What is your *web server*?  IIS?  Q: What exactly is your app?  For example, are the <script> and <link> elements you showed (with the *relative* URLs) in an ASP.Net Core 3.1 app?  ASP.Net MVC 5 app?  Q: When did the problem first occur?  "What changed"?  We need more information - please update your post.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.0
In the website, only the login page use HTTPs
The only change is apply HTTPs in the login page. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post with the additional info.  But still ... if the login page contains `<script src="../Scripts/abc.js...>` (a relative path) and login page uses HTTPS ... then I'd be surprised if the login page caused mixed content errors.  Q: Have you considered simply making the whole site HTTPS?  If possible, that would actually be "best practice": https://https.cio.gov/everything